# ng-animate with ng-if and ng-include between two different routes

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate, angularjs-ng-include, angular-ng-if

I'm trying to make a transition animate between two pages.

A variable is seted on controllers `FirstCtrl` and `SecondCtrl` to make a `ng-if` control.

The problem is that the animation **works fine at the first time**, but in the nexts it doesn't work. What i'm missing?

**Routes:**

```
$routeProvider
    .when('/first', {
        templateUrl: 'views/layout.html',
        controller: 'FirstCtrl'
    })
    .when('/second',{
        templateUrl: 'views/layout.html',
        controller: 'SecondCtrl'
    })
```

**First controller:**

```
$scope.foobar = true;
```

**Second controller:**

```
$scope.foobar = false;
```

**index.html**

```
<html ng-app='appname'>
   <head> . . . </head>
   <body>
     <div ng-view></div>
   </body>
</html>
```

**layout.html**

```
<div ng-if="foobar" class="effect" ng-include="'views/foobar.html'">
</div>

<a href="/first">fade in</a> <!-- foobar on controller -->
<a href="/second">fade out</a> <!-- foobar on controller -->
```

**css (SASS):**

```
.effect {
  -webkit-transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 2s;
  transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 2s;

  &.ng-enter {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  &.ng-enter-active {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  &.ng-leave {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  &.ng-leave-active {
    opacity: 0;
  }

}

.effect.ng-enter, .effect.ng-leave{
  -webkit-transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 2s;
  -moz-transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 2s;
  -o-transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 2s;
  transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 2s;
}
```

---

**IMPORTANT:**

This is some debug to prove that the animation fully works manipulating the variable direct from the view:

```
<div ng-if="foobar" class="effect" ng-include="'views/foobar.html'">
</div>

<button ng-click="foobar=true">fade in</button> <!-- foobar on view -->
<button ng-click="foobar=false">fade out</button> <!-- foobar on view -->
```

Comment: Is using `ng-show` instead of `ng-if` a valid option for you?

Comment: Yes, its a valid option, what you mean is just change the `ng-if` to `ng-show`? If yes, did not work, even the first transition.

Comment: Well it was worth a try anyway.  Good luck.

Comment: unfortunately, you have two different `$scope.foobar` variables which have the same name.  you will need to have an outer controller, with a `foobar` variable that is independent of your view controllers, and use `$broadcast` to notify this controller that it's value needs to change.

Comment: can you show a bit more code, such as where your `ng-app` directive is, any other `ng-controller` listings, and where the `ng-view` is relative to the `ng-if`?

Comment: @Claies i'm quite new to angular, so , i will give it a try:  `ng-app` its on my `<html ng-app='appname' />`.  There is no `ng-controller` on the view and `ng-view` its on `<body><div ng-view></div></body>`.

Comment: please edit the question, don't add code in the comments

Comment: hmm, I'm not sure of a good way to accomplish what you want.  you have two different instances of the same template, referring to two different copies of the same `$scope.foobar` variable.  I'm sure that there is some way to wait for the animation to complete before binding the new instance, but I'm not 100% sure the syntax.  it will take a bit of experimentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of the ngAnimate module to show animations when a view is displayed.

Here's a Plunker showing this in action. I'm using [Animate.css](http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) and taking advantage of the ng-enter class.

```
div[ng-view].ng-enter {
    -webkit-animation: fadeInRight 1.5s;
    animation: fadeInRight 1.5s;
  }
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/kUeCBdHLuoSl73rvI9fh?p=preview

Comment: ng-view for this project has other purpose, in this case , i need to work with a ng-include instead

Comment: Here's another Plunker that shows how you can animate the ng-show. http://plnkr.co/edit/uAweJDMoRgLLjliFmasW?p=preview